# "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools"

Tags: r, devtools, install.packages

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’ in
> loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
> vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘sessioninfo’

I have already installed the package "sessioninfo" and did the  sessioninfo(), but it is still not working. I have also unistalled and reinstalled the R and Rstudio

This is the error when i install devtools:

```
* installing *source* package 'sessioninfo' ...
** package 'sessioninfo' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'cli' 3.0.1 is being loaded, but >= 3.1.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execução interrompida
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'sessioninfo'
* removing 'C:/Users/myspace/OneDrive/Documentos/R/win-library/4.1/sessioninfo'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sessioninfo’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Please edit the output of :``library(sessioninfo); sessionInfo()`` into your original question. Thanks.

Comment: Since it appears that the `devtools` package itself might be suspect, you may want to reinstall it as well as the `sessioninfo` package.